# Alinhar a UL (resultado) com o input (filtro)

Tags: html, css, algoritmo-de-busca

Estou fazendo um search de filtro, quando o usuário digita, vai aparecendo os resultados em uma UL. A UL (onde mostra os resultados do filtro) não está alinhada com o input.
Segue uma imagem para termos uma ideia:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguma ideia?

E outra pergunta: os resultados na UL não estão aparecendo no IE. Como resolver?

Segue o código:
https://jsfiddle.net/marcelpsaraiva/p40vxdmL/

Answer (score 0):

No seu código `CSS`, onde está a #lista-opcoes, ao invés de `width:100%`, substitua por `width:563px;`. Dessa maneira você consegue mudar o tamanho do campo com o tanto de pixels que você quer que o campo tenha. Segue o código corrigido abaixo:

```
  #lista-opcoes { 
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0;
        /*margin: 0;*/
        position: absolute;
        margin-top: 27px;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
        margin-left: 0;
        width:563px;
      }
```

Segue imagem de como ficou:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Igor, eu não gostaria de limitar o campo. A ideia é que tanto o campo do filtro como a UL (lista-opções) estejam com o width 100% e alinhados.